# Find Element by ID in WebView Flutter

Tags: flutter

My goal is to implement a browser within my app designed specifically to autofill certain fields. For example, using Inspect Element, I can find the name of the class of the Text Field, and then use that to autofill. So, my question is, how can I do a similar thing with the Flutter WebView, and which flutter webview package should I use to accomplish this? Thank you so much, please let me know if I should specify anything further.

TLDR: how to do document.getElementById in flutter web view

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper
Use this package, therein you can use `getElement` methode to find it.

Please always ask with some code by trying yourself.

Comment: Hi @Subair K, Kindly help on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567864/unable-to-access-webview-element-within-an-iframe-in-a-mobile-app-using-flutter

I mentioned my solution there but it isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use this.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

// Your code

html.document.getElementById('your_id');
```